# How can I determine why a call to SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty() is very slow?

Tags: winapi, device-driver

I am calling [SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertya) with the [SPDRP_DEVICEDESC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertya#spdrp_devicedesc) property and it returns [TRUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdigetdeviceregistrypropertya#return-value).

Calling this on my "Intel(R) HD Graphics 530" takes about 50ms while the same call on my "NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960M" (same laptop) takes 750ms !

This call is only returning a short string, there is no good reason I can see for it to take that long to execute.
Since this is a Win API call, is there any way for me to identify what is taking that long ?

Comment: The same way you would identify where your code spends its time: By profiling it.

Comment: @IInspectable Sure, and how do you profile a function for which you don't have the code, like SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty ?

Comment: [How to: Reference Windows symbol information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/how-to-reference-windows-symbol-information).

Comment: `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` internal call `CM_Get_DevNode_Registry_PropertyW(.. CM_DRP_DEVICEDESC..)` (use CM_* api more simply and efficient compare Setup* api).usually main time inside this call take `LoadIndirectInfString` - which parse inf file in your system. faster of all here main time and difference between different devices

Comment: @RbMm I confirm that most of the time is spent in `LoadIndirectInfString`. Using Process Monitor I could see there were some ACCESS_DENIED when the function was trying to CreateFile on oem44.pnf. Also, by running VS in admin mode (and no more access_denied) the time is cut in half, but it is still to slow to my taste. Is there anything I can do about this ?

Comment: `CreateFile` here called with `GENERIC_READ` access request. are your concrete `oem44.pnf` have not grant generic read access for say *Users* ? usually must. hard here do something, because this is very deep in api call and you not control this.

Comment: The access request is actually "Generic Write, Read Attributes" ! I also noticed that when running the exe as admin it is always fast and the access request is only "read"... Also, when I run the exe (as normal user) many times in a row, it is sometimes fast. Not sure what could trigger the access request difference though. It could be a winapi issue or even a Nvidia issue. Not sure where/who to report this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Windows symbol information as suggested by @IInspectable and tracing in disassembly helps point to the slow functions, but it doesn't provide a solution to the issue as the code cannot be modified.
Also using [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) helps in finding the reason of the slow benchmark.

For now, the only workaround found to make the call faster is to run the process as admin.